# Get first available index in the table, including 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `player_chest`, which has the following fields:

```sql
idx integer NOT NULL,
player_id integer NOT NULL,
chest_id integer NOT NULL,
```

I am using the following query to get the first available index in the table:

```sql
SELECT c.idx + 1 FROM player_chest c WHERE c.player_id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM player_chest c1 WHERE c1.player_id = 2 AND c1.idx = c.idx + 1
) ORDER BY c.idx;
```

Sample where the query is working:

```
chest_id | idx | player_id
       0 |   0 |         2
       1 |   1 |         2
       2 |   2 |         2
       1 |   4 |         2
```

returns 3

Sample where query is not working:
Sample where the query is working:

```
chest_id | idx | player_id
       1 |   1 |         2
       2 |   2 |         2
       1 |   4 |         2
```

returns 3, but I would like it to return 0

But it fails to return the index 0 when it is available. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I added sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution uses window functions:

```
select (case when min_idx > 0 then 0
             else 1 + min(idx) filter (where next_idx is distinct from idx + 1)
        end)
from (select pc.*,
             lead(idx) over (partition by player_id order by idx) as next_idx,
             min(idx) over (partition by player_id) as min_idx
      from player_chest pc
      where player_id = 2
     ) pc
group by player_id, min_idx;
```

If you want a version that returns `0` even if the player is not in the table, then:

```
select (case when max(min_idx) > 0 or max(min_idx) is null then 0
             else 1 + min(idx) filter (where next_idx is distinct from idx + 1)
        end)
from (select pc.*,
             lead(idx) over (partition by player_id order by idx) as next_idx,
             min(idx) over (partition by player_id) as min_idx
      from player_chest pc
      where player_id = 2
     ) pc
```

Comment: u mean if the player has no entry in the player_chest table only the second query will work?